# Is the spin of a particle always a 50/50 chance of being different after measuring it in Quantum Entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This might be hard to understand but:

Let’s say you measure a partical and it has a spin of clockwise. If you stop measuring it then remeasure it, would it have a 50/50 random chance at changing its spin? Or would it continue to have the clockwise spin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the wave function of a particle re-created after a measurement stops?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89690/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand the question but I'll give this a shot. I don't think it's common to refer to spin as "clockwise" or "counterclockwise". If we're dealing with an electron then the eigenvalues of the spin operator for a particular axis, e.g. $\hat{S}_x$ or $\hat{S}_z$ , are +/- $\frac \hbar2$, often called "spin up" or "spin down", so these are the only values you can get from a measurement, and the operators for different axes do not commute. So if you measure spin with respect to the z-axis (where you can choose the direction of the z-axis arbitrarily) and you get $+\frac \hbar2$, you now have uncertainty with respect to spin along x and y. If you now go and measure spin with respect to a different axis, let's say with respect to x, and you get $+\frac \hbar2$, you now have uncertainty about the value of spin with respect to the z axis -- the probability of getting $+\frac \hbar2$ for a z-axis spin measurement would be back to 50-50 (in the absence of external forces -- if you have, say, a fermion in a magnetic field then the expectation values / the probability of getting either $+\frac \hbar2$ or $-\frac \hbar2$ with respect to a given axis will evolve with time and will not necessarily be 50-50 ).

Answer (score 0):

> Let’s say you measure a partical and it has a spin of clockwise.

Let’s say you want to measure the spin of a subatomic particle. How you have to do this measurement? Please consider that the spin is related

- to a deflection of a moving subatomic particle in an external magnetic field (for electrons and anti-protons in one direction and for positrons and protons in the opposite direction)
- and to the magnetic dipole moment of particles (for electrons by convention the spin is anti-parallel to the magnetic dipole moment, and parallel for positrons)
- and somehow to the phenomenon that two electrons in an atom can have the same [quantum numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_number) except the spin quantum number ([Pauli exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle)).

For the first point, [deflecting an electron in the external magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force), you destroy the previous unaligned spin (because the electrons magnetic dipole moment will be aligned with the external field). In this case the previous orientation gets lost.

For the second point we could observe the spin orientation of subatomic particles of atoms or molecules by applying an external magnetic field and measuring the relaxation time by the emitted EM radiation [(MRI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging). In this case you indeed get some information about the spin orientation and could do this again and again.

So for bonded particles you have a chance to measure the spin state many times, for free particles you will destroy the previous orientation of the spin.